# Building a conditional question and answers through JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am trying to build a question and answer based on `conditional` flows.

Let's take my question in UI is below JSON:

```
    {
      "text": "What is the best cookie?",
      "type": "mc",
      "answers": [
        "Chocolate Chip",
        "Sugar",
        "Beer"
      ],
      "answer": "Sugar"
    }
```

Let's take if the user selects `Sugar` and `Beer` as an option, I have put up a question from below JSON which maps to the selected answer if he chooses Beer then a different question from the `JSON object`.

If the user answers A and B for the first question, then the next question should be 3rd object in JSON, if C then 2nd Object from JSON, if C and A then the first Object from JSON.

Below is entire mock JSON I have

```
{
  "title": "Quiz about Foo",
  "questions": [
    {
      "text": "Is true true?",
      "type": "tf",
      "answer": "t"
    },
    {
      "text": "Is false true?",
      "type": "tf",
      "answer": "f"
    },
    {
      "text": "What is the best beer?",
      "type": "mc",
      "answers": [
        "Coors",
        "Miller",
        "Bud",
        "Anchor Steam"
      ],
      "answer": "Anchor Steam"
    },
    {
      "text": "What is the best cookie?",
      "type": "mc",
      "answers": [
        "Chocolate Chip",
        "Sugar",
        "Beer"
      ],
      "answer": "Sugar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please know that asking for a framework/library is off-topic. So this question will be closed if it's not changed. Consider asking a specific question about something you _have already tried_?

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox, i am not sure how to frame this up entire question. The above is the best i came up... based on the previous response i need to decide the next response to the user to display.

Comment: (I don't mean to sound rude) Try writing code of your own?

Comment: Agree with evolutionxbox... It doesn't seem like something of great complexity. It's just a matter of writing some logic to control the flow of the questions e.g. by defining dependencies between questions. If you do find some library out there, it can often be as hard to get your data to fit the library than it is to just write the logic yourself

Comment: @evolutionxbox What i am missing is not the code, but i don't know how to build this conditional JSON or the right way to build the association.

Comment: What is conditional JSON?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Lets take For a given answer (A and C), I need to bring the third object in the JSON. So there must be some association between first object and third object in the JSON for the given answer (A and C). How to map that association JSON, so that i loop through and bring it up.

Comment: Put in a property which says which questions must be correct first? This seems like trying to force the data to fit some business logic...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. If you want each answer to point to the next question in your JSON, you have to add some kind of a question ID. You also need to convert your answers from strings to objects, so you can add the ID of the next question to them.

Something like:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "What is the best cookie?",
      "type": "mc",
      "answers": [
        { "text": "Chocolate Chip", "nextQuestionId": 2 },
        { "text": "Sugar", "nextQuestionId": 2 },
        { "text": "Beer", "nextQuestionId": 3 }
      ],
      "answer": "Sugar"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Second question?",
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "Third question?",
      ...
    }    
  ]
}
```

This way you can write a simple generic logic that just follows the flow defined by the JSON.